# Script for checking health on disks

Tags: scripts

I want to use HDsentinel to auto check the health of my disks. I have a larger script that this is going to be included in.

So here's my problem:
If I run  `./HDSentinel -solid | grep 953870 | awk '{print $1,$3}'` I'll get the following output:

```
/dev/sda 100
/dev/sdb 100
/dev/sdc 100
/dev/sdd 100
/dev/sde 100
/dev/sdf 100
```

This says that all my disks are at 100% health. But I want to print to a file what disk(s) are under 100% with the following command:

```
./HDSentinel -aam | grep -A13 /dev/diskid >> file
```

It desn't need to be the grep command here but you the idea is the same.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
grep --invert-match '100$'
```

This will find all lines that do not have 100 at the very end of the line.

Comment: Of course! thank you!!! I'll post my script here when I have time to finish it.